# http.post angularjs 404 error

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I'm trying to post form data to a mongodb (moongose) using the angularjs http.post method and I'm getting a 404 error not sure I'm doing this correctly. It complains it cant find the url -> POST http://localhost:5000/tournaments/56bf2ea58e5ea932088ff356/games 404 (Not Found)

###### This is my api router

```
router.post('/tournaments/:id/games', function(req, res) {

  var newGame  = {};
  newGame.id = req.body.id;
  newGame.gameDate = req.body.gameDate;
  newGame.homeTeam = req.body.homeTeam;
  newGame.awayTeam = req.body.awayTeam;
  newGame.homeTeamScore = req.body.homeTeamScore;
  newGame.awayTeamScore = req.body.awayTeamScore;
  newGame.hadOT = req.body.hadOT;
  newGame.hadSO = req.body.hadSO;

  Tournament.update({ "_id": req.params.id}, {$push: {games: newGame}}, function(err, model) {
    if(err) {
      res.send(err)
    } else {
      res.json(model)
    }
  });
});
```

this is in the controller

```
vm.isEditing = false;
 vm.newGame = {
  awayTeam: '',
  homeTeam: '',
  homeTeamScore: 0,
  awayTeamScore: 0
};
vm.showModal = function() {
  vm.isEditing = true;
}
vm.hideModal = function() {
  vm.isEditing = false;
  vm.addGameForm.$setPristine();
  vm.isSaving = true;
}

vm.addGame = function() {
  vm.isSaving = true;
  vm.newGame.id = vm.selectedTournament.games.length + 1;
  $http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : '/tournaments/'+tournamentId+'/games',
      data    : $.param($scope.vm.newGame),
      headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
  }).success(function(response){
      $scope.vm.newGame = {};
      $scope.games = response;
      console.log(response);
  })
  .error(function(data) {
    console.log('Error: ' + data);
  });

  vm.addGameForm.$setPristine();
  vm.hideModal();

}
```

Comment: It's not clear why you need `$scope` in your controller from your example, if you have newGame on scope already with `vm.newGame` (assuming you're using controllerAs syntax in your html).  Apart from that, does the `tournaments/56bf2ea58e5ea932088ff356` document already exist? Are you sure the data is coming across in the body of the request? What is the exact error?

Comment: My apology. $scope should not be there(I'm using vm as controller). The tournament file is there as a giant file containing all tournaments. If I do http://localhost:5000/tournaments I'll get the full json output.{
_id: "56bf2ea58e5ea932088ff356",
commissioner: "5642a4fbf6cb4e0300912c26",
name: "thetournament",
__v: 0,
playoffGames: [ ],
games: [ ],
teams: [
{
_id: "56b91370f5ccff0300b8be29",
__v: 0,
city: "Buffalo, NY",
league: "NHL",
name: "Buffalo Sabres",
isselected: true,
player1: "5627f66b7146710300e9281f",
player2: "564294d6556a120300047078"
}
]
}

Comment: If I do http://localhost:5000/tournaments/5642a4fbf6cb4e0300912c26 I get an empty array []

Comment: That's the commissioner id, so that makes sense. Do you have a get route set up for /tournaments/:id? If you want to continue in the chat room, I can try to help you there.

Comment: figured it out. The route is supposed to be /api/tournaments/56bf2ea58e5ea932088ff356

Comment: Thanks for your help Bennett